# Error : Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, I've tried to read the documentation of CI but I still can't solve my problem, maybe someone here can help fix my problem. Here is my code:

In my controller

```
class Registration extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('registration_model','rmod');
    }

    function ambil() {

        $gender = $this->input->post('kelamin');  

        $tinggi = $this->input->post('height'); 

        $berat  = $this->input->post('weight');

        $weight = $this->rmod->ambilBeratPria($tinggi);

        echo $weight;
    }
```

In my model

```
function ambilBeratPria($tinggi) {

    $this->db->select('berat')->from('pria')->where('tinggi',$tinggi);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;           
}
```

I want to get the result of my query in the model, but i get an error like this:

**`Message:  Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string`**

Maybe someone here can help to solve my problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return the result of the query:

```
function ambilBeratPria($tinggi) {

     $this->db->select('berat')->from('pria')->where('tinggi',$tinggi);

     $query = $this->db->get();

     return $query->result();

}
```

EDIT:

If the result is a single row:

```
function ambilBeratPria($tinggi) {

     $this->db->select('berat')->from('pria')->where('tinggi',$tinggi);

     $query = $this->db->get();

     if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
         return $query->row()->berat;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ^^
i've tried that way. the return is not the result of the query but just an "array" text came out when i ran the code...
maybe i got wrong on the controller code ??

Comment: when i try, i got an error like this "Trying to get property of non-object" 
maybe my code is still wrong ? ^^

Comment: It means there is no result. You can check to see `if $query->num_rows() > 0` before returning the result.

Comment: Great !! it Works ! thank you very much, i really much appreciate it ^^

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer which helped you the most.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you're trying to directly echo the value returned by `$this->db->get();`. However, to use the result(s) from the query, you need to [generate the results.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

If you generate the query like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Then there are several options for generating results. These examples assume that you have a column in the row(s) being returned called *weight*.

---

**`result()`** - Allows you to use the results as an *array of objects*.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  //Ensure that there is at least one result 
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)  //Iterate through results
   {
      echo $row->weight;
   }
}
```

---

**`result_array()`** - Allows you to use the results as an *array*.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  //Ensure that there is at least one result 
{    
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) //Iterate through results
    {
        echo $row['weight'];
    }
}
```

---

**`row()`** - If you're expecting only one result then this can be useful. If the query generates multiple results, then only the *first row* is returned. Allows you to use the result as an *object*.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $row = $query->row();   
   echo $row->weight;
}
```

---

**`row_array()`** - The same as `row()` but allows you to use the result as an *array*.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $row = $query->row_array(); 
   echo $row['weight'];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, i really much appreciate it ! ^^ it worked ^^

Comment: No worries, I'm pleased it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I was working in a PHP project with Code Igniter framework.In there in my model class there was a method called getprojectnames(),

```
public function getprojectnames(){

                                    $result['names']=array();
                                    $this->db->select('name');
                                    $this->db->from('project');
                                    $this->db->where('status','Not Completed');
                                    $query=$this->db->get();
                                    return  $query->result();
                                    }
```

I wanted to call this function in the controller class and use it in a drop down list in the view class.

So in my controller class,

```
   $this->data['projects'] =$this->testcase_model->getprojectnames();
   $this->load->view("admin/_layout_main",$this->data);
```

In my view class,

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/check1'); ?>
    <div class="row" style=" margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 15px;">
        <h5 class="box-title">Projects List &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : &nbsp; <?             php echo form_dropdown('projects', $projects, 'id'); ?> </h5>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" style="width:200px;" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Show Project TestCase Status" /></div>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

When I run this I got the error,telling CI_DB_mysql_result could not convert into String.So I solved this problem by changing my code in the model class like as follows,

```
public function getprojectnames(){

                                    $result['names']=array();
                                    $this->db->select('name');
                                    $this->db->from('project');
                                    $this->db->where('status','Not Completed');
                                    $query=$this->db->get();

                                     foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                                        {
                                           array_push($result,$row->name);
                                        }
                                     return $result;

                                       }
```

Then my program worked fine.